# Can't load image from file in GDI+ C++, tried Bitmap::FromFile() and Image::FromFile()

Tags: c++, bitmap, gdi+

```
Image* myImage = Image::FromFile(L"flag.png");
Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap = Bitmap::FromFile(L"flag.png",false);
```

The Program complies however, in debugging myImage says outOfMemory when it tries to load in the image and bitmap says invalid parameters when it tries to load in the image. The resource flag.png is in the project folder.

Comment: Both error codes mean the same thing.  You don't have enough address space left to load the image.  You are out of memory.  Use a [memory profiler](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/10/21/memory-profiling-in-visual-c-2015/) if you have no idea how you squandered 2 gigabytes.  Or target x64.

Comment: Or, possibly, that the file is not a .PNG or is corrupt.  Have you tried opening the same file in Explorer?

Comment: Don't think there is a memory profiler for visual studio 2010, will see if i can use a 3rd party application though. The file isn't corrupt, I have opened and checked it. Thanks for the advice both.

Comment: Did you call this function from a new (not main) thread? Was it the first time you called it in your code?